# How do I change the color of a PushButton when another button is pressed(PyQT5, QT)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

Hello for my application, I am trying to change the color of one button when different button is pressed.

I am doing this by creating a global boolean variable called changeSymbol, and one of the buttons will change when the changeSymbol returns true.

Here is my code:
[EDIT Due to difficulties in copy and pasting (also I am new to stack overflow) I will post screenshots instead]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry but your code doesn't make a lot of sense to us (and only classes and constants should have capitalized names, not functions or variables/attributes): what calls `Clear_changed`? And what calls `Change_pressed`? Also, the return value of `changeSymbol` is not use, so it's meaningless. Please try to be more clear in explaining what you're actually trying to achieve, and provide a proper [mre].

Comment: if you have both buttons in the same class then you should use `self.` to keep buttons and access directly second button and change its color.

Comment: maybe you should run `Clear_changed()` directly in `changeSymbol()` instead of `return changeMode`. Or maybe you should put code from all functions into `Change_pressed()` and then you don't need any global variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand problem because I can't see full code.

Maybe you should do all in one function

```
def Change_pressed(self):
    if self.Change.isChecked():
        self.Change.setText("")
        self.Clear.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                 "  background-color: RGB (107, 128, 104) ;\n"
                                 "  border: 1px solid gray;\n"
                                 "}\n"
                                 "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
                                 "    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
                                 "                                      stop: 0 #BEBEBE, stop: 1 #D7D7D7);\n"
                                 "}")

    else:
        self.Change.setText("")
        self.Clear.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                 "  background-color: rgb(215, 215, 215);\n"
                                 "  border: 1px solid gray;\n"
                                 "}\n"
                                 "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
                                 "    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
                                 "                                      stop: 0 #BEBEBE, stop: 1 #D7D7D7);\n"
                                 "}")
```

---

And if you have to keep code in separated functions then you could use `self.changeMode` instead of global variable. And also run `Clear_changed()` in `Change_pressed()

```
def Change_pressed(self):
    self.changeSymbol()
    self.Clear_changed()
    
def changeSymbol(self):
    if self.Change.isChecked():
        self.Change.setText("")
        self.changeMode = True
    else:
        self.Change.setText("")
        self.changeMode = False

def Clear_changed(self):
    if self.changeMode == True:
        self.Clear.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                 "  background-color: RGB (107, 128, 104) ;\n"
                                 "  border: 1px solid gray;\n"
                                 "}\n"
                                 "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
                                 "    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
                                 "                                      stop: 0 #BEBEBE, stop: 1 #D7D7D7);\n"
                                 "}")
    else:
        self.Clear.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
                                 "  background-color: rgb(215, 215, 215);\n"
                                 "  border: 1px solid gray;\n"
                                 "}\n"
                                 "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
                                 "    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
                                 "                                      stop: 0 #BEBEBE, stop: 1 #D7D7D7);\n"
                                 "}")
```

Comment: Hello, I apologize for the late reply, please reply back or edit answer because I have posted the full code by the time I have typed the comment

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution, it helps a lot. But now I have two more problems, one is the color change, it turns dark grey instead of the specific color I want, and two, the button appears to shrink whenever I press change, I want it to stay the same size

Comment: Fixed it: instead of set style sheet and list a lot of things I just specify background color, thank you so much once again